# what is a target site Url

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

What is the targetSiteUrl and InfrastructureSiteUrl in sharepoint. I was reading an example on this site :

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive

Answer (score 1):

if you see the descriptions on the same link, it explain it.

**TargetSiteurl** URL of the Site Collection where the Responsive UI will be enabled. It has to be provided as a full URL, like for example: https://intranet.mydomain.com/sites/targetSite or https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteCollection

**InfrastructureSiteUrl**   URL of an infrastructural Site Collection, where will be uploaded/updated the JavaScript and CSS files backing the Responsive UI solution. If you don't provide a value for this parameter, the cmdlet will use the target Site Collection to host these files. It has to be provided as a full URL, like for example: https://intranet.mydomain.com/sites/infrastructureSite or https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/infrastructureSite

**Example:**

```
PS C:\> .\Enable-SPResponsiveUI.ps1 -TargetSiteurl "https://intranet.mydomain.com/sites/targetSite"
```

This will enable the Responsive UI on targetSiteURL and also host the script files on same site. Butif you use -InfrastructureSiteUrl then it will store the files on that url.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. where is the target url in the sharepoint site.

Comment: that is your site collection url...on which site you are trying to enable the UI...http://sitename

Comment: oh thanks, but my site collection url does not end with /sites/infrastructureSite. it that ok? sorry just new to sharepoint.

Comment: then either your site collection is host name or root of the web application...but it should be ok